# Write a Sparse Matrix to a CSV in R

Tags: r, statistics, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse matrix (`dgCMatrix`) as the result of fitting a `glmnet`. I want to write this result to a `.csv` but can't use `write.table()` the matrix because it can't coerced into a `data.frame`.

Is there a way to coerce the sparse matrix to either a `data.frame` or a regular matrix? Or is there a way to write it to a file while keeping the coefficient names which are probably row names?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`as.matrix()` will convert to the full dense representation:

```
> as.matrix(Matrix(0, 3, 2))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    0    0
[3,]    0    0
```

You can write the resulting object out using `write.csv` or `write.table`.

Comment: I tried matrix() and it didn't work, I didn't think to try as.matrix().  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 15):

That will be dangerous to transform the sparse matrix to a normal one, if the sparse matrix size is too large. In my case (text classification task), I got a matrix of size 22490 by 120,000. If you try get the dense matrix, that will be more than 20 GB, I think. Then R will break down !

So my suggestion, you may simply store the sparse matrix in an efficient and memory friendly way, such as **[Matrix Market Format](http://math.nist.gov/MatrixMarket/formats.html)**, which keeps all non-zero values and their coordinates (row & col number). In the R you can use the method **writeMM**

Answer (score 6):

Converting directly to a dense matrix is likely to waste a lot of memory. The R package Matrix allows converting the sparse matrix into a memory-efficient coordinate triplet format data frame using the `summary()` function, which could then be written easily to csv. This is probably simpler and easier than the matrix market approach. See the answer to this related question: [Sparse matrix to a data frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12029177/sparse-matrix-to-a-data-frame-in-r?rq=1)

Also, here is an illustration from the [Matrix package documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/Matrix/html/externalFormats.html):

```
## very simple export - in triplet format - to text file:
data(CAex)
s.CA <- summary(CAex)
s.CA # shows  (i, j, x)  [columns of a data frame]
message("writing to ", outf <- tempfile())
write.table(s.CA, file = outf, row.names=FALSE)
## and read it back -- showing off  sparseMatrix():
str(dd <- read.table(outf, header=TRUE))
## has columns (i, j, x) -> we can use via do.call() as arguments to sparseMatrix():
mm <- do.call(sparseMatrix, dd)
stopifnot(all.equal(mm, CAex, tolerance=1e-15))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
# input: a sparse matrix with named rows and columns (dimnames)
# returns: a data frame representing triplets (r, c, x) suitable for writing to a CSV file
sparse2triples <- function(m) {
 SM = summary(m)
 D1 = m@Dimnames[[1]][SM[,1]]
 D2 = m@Dimnames[[2]][SM[,2]]
 data.frame(row=D1, col=D2, x=m@x)
}
```

#### Example

```
> library(Matrix)
> dn <- list(LETTERS[1:3], letters[1:5])
> m <- sparseMatrix(i = c(3,1,3,2,2,1), p= c(0:2, 4,4,6), x = 1:6, dimnames = dn)

> m
3 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
  a b c d e
A . 2 . . 6
B . . 4 . 5
C 1 . 3 . .

> sparse2triples(m)
  row col x
1   C   a 1
2   A   b 2
3   B   c 4
4   C   c 3
5   A   e 6
6   B   e 5
```

[EDIT: use data.frame]

Comment: Please do add an explanation as it will be easier to understand

Comment: This worked for me (which was taken from your answer)

  SM = summary(mat0)

  D1 = nrow(mat0)

  D2 = nrow(mat0)

  a<-as.matrix(data.frame(row=D1, col=D2, x=SM))