# dgTMatrix export to csv

Tags: r, csv

I'm working on bioinformatic data, and the object I have generated so far in a large dgTMatrix which I'm trying to export into a csv file I could open and check regardless of the size.

I'm working with R, and when I write the line

```
write.csv(A.data, "Adata.csv")
```

I get the following error:

> Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : cannot coerce class "structure("dgTMatrix", package = "Matrix")" to a data.frame

From what I understand, a dgTMatrix might not be directly convertible into a classic table, but I cannot find what extra step I need to nail to be able to have my csv file in the end.

Any help and pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12029177/sparse-matrix-to-a-data-frame-in-r)

Comment: @RobertMc this actually doesn't seem to be applicable in my case. I get the following sum objet: 
`Length  Class   Mode
     1 seurat     S4`

Answer (score 0):

If `A.data` is a sparse matrix, meaning, an object such that `class()`returns

```
class(A.data)
#[1] "dgTMatrix"
#attr(,"package")
#[1] "Matrix"
```

then you need to coerce it to class `"matrix"` or class `"data.frame"` before writing to disk with `write.csv2`.

```
A.data<-as.matrix(A.data)
write.csv2(A.data, "Adata.csv")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thanks for posting your first answer. While code-only answers can be legitimate, it is generally more helpful to explain your answer. Please consider [editing your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58884615/edit) to add more details if possible.