# How to convert Sparse Matrix to Sparse DataFrame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse matrix with 20 million rows and 2 million columns.
How to convert it to Sparse DataFrame in R.

---

"speedglm" package only take dataframe as input, But it seems that "as.data.frame" has no argument for sparse.

Comment: You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12029177/sparse-matrix-to-a-data-frame-in-r)

Comment: it seems doesnt work for me, because the answer is not sparse dataframe

Comment: Why do you believe that speedglm can deal with sparse data structures as input? Even if there was such a thing as a "Sparse DataFrame", speedglm would still need to be able to handle that. I can't find any hint in the documentation that it can do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
df<-data.frame(your matrix)
```