# Converting an extremely large R S4 dgCMatrix to data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, sparse-matrix, seurat

I have an extremely big sparse matrix (4,941,643,682 elements, 5.6Gb R object in memory) that I need to convert to a 3-column data.frame (row, column, value) and then dump it into a text file for further processing.

I have tried the "summary" method [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12029177/sparse-matrix-to-a-data-frame-in-r) with no luck (I have previously used this method successfully in other datasets). Due to the "S4 nature" of the data, the summary method no longer returns a matrix, but just this description.

```
> typeof(mat)
[1] "S4"
> summary(mat)
    Length      Class       Mode 
4941643682  dgCMatrix         S4
```

Trying to cast the object into a matrix also doesn't work:

```
> matrix(mat)
Error in as.vector(.Call(Csparse_to_vector, x), mode) : 
  Cholmod error 'problem too large' at file ../Core/cholmod_dense.c, line 105
```

This data comes from an hdf5 file that I had to open using the **Seurat** package.

```
library(Seurat)
library(hdf5r)

tt<-ReadH5AD(file = "input.h5ad",assay = "RNA", layers = "data", verbose = TRUE)

mat<-GetAssayData(tt, assay="RNA",slot="data")
```

I have also tried using the Seurat::as.sparse() function, but it returns the same type of S4 object that I cannot convert to data.frame. And "as.data.frame" and "as.data.frame.matrix" attempt to create a 245k-column x 20k-row data.frame.

Is there an S4 method to convert a sparse matrix to a "rowname","colname","value" data.frame?

Comment: Try `selectMethod("summary", "dgCMatrix")(mat)`? What does `class(mat)` return? Obviously, you can't turn such a large sparse matrix into a dense matrix (using `matrix` or `as.matrix`).

Comment: Oh thanks! That worked perfectly! 
BTW, class(mat) returned `> class(mat)
[1] "dgCMatrix"
attr(,"package")
[1] "Matrix"`
`> typeof(mat)
[1] "S4"`

Comment: Don't know why method dispatch doesn't work correctly then. Might be worth reporting this to the Seurat maintainer.

Comment: “*dump it into a text file*” - I’m pretty sure the MatrixMarket format is basically a (row, column, value) text file, so it seems like `Matrix::writeMM(mat, “mat.mtx”)` would work, i.e., skipping the intermediate conversion.